# PHP include for just homepage in wordpress (genesis framework)

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I'm using the Genesis framework and trying to add some bits under the content.

I want them to appear on just the homepage, so I'm currently using this code, however it's including on all pages.

I have a feeling the if statement is wrong...

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'sp_homepage_content' );
function sp_homepage_content() {
    if ( is_page('2') )
       include ('includes/homepage-content.php');
}
```

EDIT:
I think i fixed it with the following:

```
    add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'sp_homepage_content' );
function sp_homepage_content() {
    ?>
    <?php if ( is_page('2') ) { include ('includes/homepage-content.php');} else ?>
    <?php
}
```

Although I'm not sure if that's "good" code... It works

Comment: Try to use `if(is_home())`.

Comment: Thanks, I actually think I fixed it with this:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition to `if(is_home())`.

```
add_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'sp_homepage_content' );
function sp_homepage_content() {
    if ( is_home() )
       include ('includes/homepage-content.php');
}
```